# System.windows.media Assembley

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

How can i add assembly for System.windows.media to site who configure to asp.net 3.5..

I got the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: why are you adding a wpf assembly for asp.net?

Comment: for ckeditor upload image  http://www.wizbay.com/post/2010/09/08/Upload-image-files-using-ckeditor-in-AspNet-VB-C-Jquery.aspx

Comment: @Bside because I must go off computer, and I can not verify the details of my answer I delete it for the moment. sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find System.Windows.Media namepspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154198/cant-find-system-windows-media-namepspace)

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the dlls: presentationcore.dll & windowsbase.dll and it's work !