# Where to add reference for System.Windows.Media.GradientStopCollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, gradientstop

I have gone to the "Reference" in Solution Explorer and tried to add it from "Framework" under "Assemblies" in the Reference Manager. Is there something that I'm missing in term of having a service pack installed? The MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientstopcollection.aspx)

In VS 2010

please advise... Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find System.Windows.Media namepspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154198/cant-find-system-windows-media-namepspace)

Answer (score 7):

See the documentation:

> **Namespace**:  System.Windows.Media
>   **Assembly**:  PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll)

You need to add a reference to `PresentationCore`, and add `using System.Windows.Media` to your file.

You may already have both.

Comment: I did that, but it is still not working for Matrices.  (It does give a new library for Color tho...).  Any ideas?

Comment: @Evorlor: See the documentation to find out where the type you want is defined.

Comment: It's in System.Windows.Media