# Cannot add "using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;" in WPF desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I need to use the `BitmapImage` class which is part of the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace.

From Visual Studio 2012 Express, I started with a WPF desktop application project template, and I can see the relevant dll, `PresentationCore.dll` is present under the references.

[This link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) indicates this reference should be sufficient. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fdfff143-c1ae-41cd-bbeb-8ff6c1c879ec/cannot-find-systemwindowsmediaimaging-namespace?forum=windowswic) indicates the same, and highlights the fact that the necessary dll is referenced by default  when using a typical wpf project template in VS2012.

And yet, in my C# code behind, the compiler complains on my `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` statement that `Media` cannot be found.

This problem seems to not be uncommon, and yet I found no solution to it.

**UPDATE:**
When looking at the properties for the reference to PresentationCore.dll, I see that version is 4.0.0.0 and runtime version is 4.0.30319. I am making a cheap relation to the fact that BitmapImage exists only for .net 4.5 supposedly... Could this be a hint to the problem ?

Comment: The versions you're seeing are correct. Also, `BitmapImage` exists since .NET 3.0.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154198/cant-find-system-windows-media-namepspace has more explicit answers to the above question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 required references need for a WPF project, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework and WindowsBase. See [WPF Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [WPF Architecture - and overview ...](http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/03/wpf-architecture-overview-of-windows.html#.UtPJ4fQW20U) . The second one has a nice description of the contents of the libraries.