# Why does this sample TIFF import code result in errors?

Tags: c#, decode, tiff

I read [How to: Encode and Decode a TIFF Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-tiff-image) and copied the code

```
// Open a Stream and decode a TIFF image
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream("tulipfarm.tif", FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, 
BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

// Draw the Image
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Source = bitmapSource;
myImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
myImage.Margin = new Thickness(20);
```

into a console app in Visual Studio 2017.  I added a reference to PresentationCore per https://stackoverflow.com/a/50192029/9044571 and that allowed me to add

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

But now I am getting an error (Error    CS0144  Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Image') associated with the line

```
Image myImage = new Image();
```

How might I fix this?  Could the problem be that I am doing this from a console app?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is, you are actually targeting the [`System.Drawing.Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.7.2) *class* which is *abstract*

Fix is to either to :-

1. Remove the wrong *Namespace*
2. Using an *Namespace alias*

[Namespace Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#namespace-aliases)

> The using Directive can also be used to create an alias for a
>   namespace. For example, if you are using a previously written
>   namespace that contains nested namespaces, you might want to declare
>   an alias to provide a shorthand way of referencing one in particular,
>   as in the following example:
>
> ```
> using Co = Company.Proj.Nested;  // define an alias to represent a namespace
> ```

3. Explicitly target the correct one

   `var myImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Image();`

Comment: Thanks.  var myImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Image(); resulted in Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Image' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging' (are you missing an assembly reference?)