# Can't find System.Windows.Media.editing namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm trying to add the namespace "system.windows.media.editing" but I can not add it, at first it did not recognize the "media" so I added presentation.dll, but now it does not allow me to add the "edit", I am using the .net 5.0 version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find System.Windows.Media namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154198/cant-find-system-windows-media-namespace)

Comment: Hi, @ yair.
Do you want to use the [**system.windows.media**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media?view=net-5.0) namespace or the [**windows.media.editing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.editing?view=winrt-19041) namespace?
1. You can use the **system.windows.media** namespace directly when you create a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications in visual studio 2019.
2. Generally,  you could use the **windows.media.editing** namespace in UWP.